# Why (when?) can event.target be null?

Tags: typescript

I guess everything is in the title: When is event.target null, as allowed by its typing definition?

I don't think I ever encountered the case and couldn't find an explanation in the doc, either on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) or on typescript's typings code itself (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4992)

Comment: You can just create `Event` object with no target.

Answer (score 2):

you can see this simple example

```
const evt = new Event('any', {});
console.log(evt.target);
```

So: not every event has a target :)